# Unexpected slowness of FindShortestTour through 9 points

Tags: mathematical-optimization, windows, timing

This a very useful function, but it is very slow:

```
FindShortestTour[{{0, 0}, {0.2`, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 2.5`}, {1.5`,
6}, {1.6`, 7}, {1.4`, 8}, {1.9`, 10}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.80721, Null}

I tested just 9 points, which cost me almost $2s$. I think there is a bug is behind this behavior. So I reported to Wolfram Support (**CASE:3847386**), but I received a response like：

> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support.
>
> I followed your example and evaluated it on my machine:
>
> ```
> FindShortestTour[{{0, 0}, {0.2`, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 2.5`}, {1.5`, 6}, {1.6`, 7}, 
>       {1.4`, 8}, {1.9`, 10}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
> (* {0.0847348,Null} *)
> ```
>
> Please consider resetting Mathematica and see if the issue can be resolved.

My processor is a  [Intel® Core™ i5-6500 Processor](http://ark.intel.com/ru/products/88184/Intel-Core-i5-6500-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz), and when I run `` Needs["Benchmarking`"];
Benchmarking`BenchmarkReport[] ``, my system scored $1.29$ *WolframMark* points. Many time show it is a very low efficency function:

```
Table[
 First[
  FindShortestTour[
   {{0, 0}, {0.2`, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 2.5`}, {1.5`, 6}, {1.6`, 7},
    {1.4`, 8}, {1.9`, 10}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
 ], 
 5
]
```

> {2.43196,2.01361,2.37832,1.97023,1.78632}

I would like to confirm whether some bug in this function is causing this behavior.

---

### Update

This is a regression of version 11.0, and just on Windows:

#### test on windows

[image]

#### test on mac

[image]

#### test on linux

[image]

Comment: I get 0.089819 seconds on a Mac running v. 10.4.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks,desire to see a v11.0.1 tester,which can help me give a further response.

Comment: I get 0.005714 seconds on a MacBookPro (new model), Version 11.0.1 of Mathematica

Comment: I get {0.007223, Null} on my i5 6400 running 11.0. On that benchmark function I get between 1.89 and 2.20

Comment: Can we confirm this as Windows-specific?  On my mac I get less than 10 ms for any version, but my deskmate uses windows and found in version 11 that `RepeatedTiming` was taking longer than he was interested in letting it run.

Comment: @JasonB. I think it also is just on Windows.

Comment: @yode There is no "i6500U" processor, probably you mean [Intel® Core™ i5-6500 Processor](http://ark.intel.com/ru/products/88184/Intel-Core-i5-6500-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz)?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for catch that,I have fixed that typo.

Answer (score 3):

This is a comment, to confirm that I see the unreasonably slow results as well. My system is a reasonably recent dual-core laptop running Win7-64. I tried the same calculation on MMA 11 and 10.4.

My results (shown below) seem to support the observation that `FindShortestTour` is awfully slow on recent MMA implementations **on the Windows platform**; notice also that there the performance seems to have worsened from MMA 10.4 to MMA 11.0 on Windows.

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {0.2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 2.5}, {1.5, 6}, {1.6, 7}, {1.4, 8}, {1.9, 10}};
```

---

```
$Version
(* "10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)" *)

FindShortestTour[pts]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {6.738, Null} *)
```

---

```
$Version
(* "11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)" *)

FindShortestTour[pts]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {7.24, Null} *)
```

Comment: The *WL* just think this phenomenon appear in specific machine.

Comment: @yode Perhaps others with MMA 11 on Windows machines will chime in as well and report their experience.

Comment: On my 8-years old Lenovo R500 laptop running Windows 7 x64 I get timings `0.0426` sec with version 11.0.0 and `0.044` sec with version 10.4.1. My laptop has Intel processor (Mobile DualCore Intel Core 2 Duo P8400, 2400 MHz). Which processor is installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the `` GraphComputation`LegacyFindShortestTour `` always faster than `FindShortestTour`

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
```

#### `` GraphComputation`LegacyFindShortestTour ``

```
AbsoluteTiming[First[GraphComputation`LegacyFindShortestTour[pts]]]
```

> `{0.00929029,2.90719}`

#### `FindShortestTour`

```
AbsoluteTiming[First[FindShortestTour[pts]]]
```

> `{0.687586,2.90719}`