# How to get a pair with smallest total distance from one list in high-efficiency method

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

This is similar to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141176/how-to-get-some-pairing-with-smallest-total-distance-in-high-effciency-method), but actually more complicated. I have two lists in that question, and I want to get a pair. But in here, I want to get a pair from one list (even points). Given these `20` points:

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomInteger[20, {20, 2}]
```

> `{{5,0},{7,0},{2,3},{0,0},{16,14},{3,8},{19,5},{18,16},{12,0},{19,4},{7,3},{0,4},{20,3},{5,12},{19,8},{11,2},{3,10},{4,2},{17,11},{15,6}}`

I can use `FindIndependentEdgeSet` to get one pair like this:

```
g = CompleteGraph[20];
List @@@ FindIndependentEdgeSet[VertexReplace[g, Thread[VertexList[g] -> pts]]]
```

> `{{{5,0},{7,0}},{{2,3},{3,8}},{{0,0},{16,14}},{{19,5},{4,2}},{{18,16},{3,10}},{{12,0},{7,3}},{{19,4},{11,2}},{{0,4},{20,3}},{{5,12},{19,8}},{{17,11},{15,6}}}`

The total distance is

```
Total[EuclideanDistance @@@ pair] // N
```

> 113.859

But I'm sure it is not the smallest pair. Actually, I think I need a `FindIndependentEdgeSet` of edge weight version, but it seems the `FindIndependentEdgeSet`  regards weighted graph as unweighted directly. Can anyone give me advice? Of course, I'm happy to know other methods that can do this which aren't based on *Graph Theory*.

---

This post related [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1073493) question.

Comment: Are you interested only in a perfect solution, i.e. *the* minimal weight pairing, or would an optimization approach that produces a "good" pairing be useful too?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just expected the optimal paring and hope to speed up it. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard A brute force look shows the min distance with `SeedRandom[1]` to be 30.8036. This takes ~100s to run for the 20 point case and scales badly (`Binomial[2 n, n]`)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives the same (optimal) result as Daniel Lichtblau's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144762/4330) for the given example. Integer linear programming is also used, but in this answer this is done by `FindShortestTour`.

```
max = 20;
nn = 20;
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomInteger[max, {nn, 2}]
boolPts =
  Join[
   Transpose@Join[{-Range[nn]}, Transpose@ pts], 
   Table[{i, 0, 0}, {i,  nn}]];
bound = 2 max^2;
tour = FindShortestTour[
   boolPts,
    DistanceFunction -> (If[#[[1]] +  #2[[1]] == 0,
       -bound,
       If[
        #[[1]] #2[[1]] < 0 
        ,
        bound
        ,
        EuclideanDistance[#[[2 ;;]], #2[[2 ;;]]]
        ]] &), Method -> "IntegerLinearProgramming"];

resultLength = nn*bound + N@First@tour
```

> ```
> 30.8036
> ```

```
pairs = pts[[#]] & /@ Partition[tour[[2]], 2][[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]
resultLength == Total[EuclideanDistance @@@ pairs]
```

> ```
> {{{5, 0}, {7, 0}}, {{5, 12}, {3, 10}}, {{0, 0}, {2, 3}}, {{11, 
>    2}, {12, 0}}, {{19, 4}, {20, 3}}, {{17, 11}, {19, 8}}, {{15, 
>    6}, {19, 5}}, {{16, 14}, {18, 16}}, {{7, 3}, {4, 2}}, {{3, 8}, {0, 
>    4}}}
>  True
> ```

Comment: Some question should be listed.Firstly,the `boolPts` can be `Catenate[MapIndexed[{PadRight[#2, 3], Prepend[#1, -First[#2]]} &, 
  pts]]`?Secondly,why we set the `bound` is `2 max^2`?.Thirdly,Do you sure the `FindShortestTour` always will give *Global minimal pairs* and have you see [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1075278)?fourthly,could you explain your `DistanceFunction`?

Comment: The result is not same with [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143193/how-to-get-a-pair-with-smallest-total-distance-from-one-list-in-high-efficiency#comment385203_143193).And how to get the pair as your `tour`?

Comment: @yode 1) yes, you can use that `Catenate` code if you prefer. 2) `bound` is set heuristically to `2 max^2`. It can be seen as a reward/penalty that has is so big that if you can get it as a reward, you will always choose to do so and similarly you always avoid it as a penalty. If you do not include a reward, my procedure may find triplets instead of pairs. It is also used as a penalty to "remove edges" between vertices. 3) I think it will always find the optimum, I think the reduction to a `FindshortestTour` (traveling salesman) problem is correct and...

Comment: `FindShortestTour` with the option `Method -> "IntegerLinearProgramming"` will give the optimal solution for the problem it is considering. 4) See my explanation under "2)". Re: "The result is not same...", well I get the same decimals right `(30.8036)`? Re: "how to get the pair(s)..", it is stored in the variable `pairs`.

Comment: @yode it was probably a bit silly of me to not use a `Graph`. I felt it might be more efficient to not have to calculate all distances between all points, but perhaps the time this takes is negligible anyway. If I make a graph the intended connections between vertices may be more apparent.

Comment: 1)If I use the `Catenate` version,I will get a wrong `pairs`. 2)I don't very understand your `DistanceFunction` still.I think it define two rules.First rule,it will connected that `{n,*,*}` and `{-n,0,0}`.Second rule,it will prefer to connect those same winding points.But I don't know why it will get a optimal pair..

Comment: @yode if `Catenate` gives the wrong pairs, then probably I should use `Select` instead of `Partition` and `Part` to get the pairs from the `tour`, I will test that in a minute.

Comment: About why it gives an optimal pair, maybe it helps to look at the variable `tour`. You see that we always have two integers `<= 20` then two integers `>20`. The integers `<= 20` correspond to the original points and they come in pairs in `tour` in that they are separated by integers `>20` (imaginary points). To see why we get pairs, note that we have `20` edges with a reward of `bound`, so the algorithm wants to jump exactly `20` times between points `{n,*,*}` and `{-n,0,0}`...

Comment: What ends up happening is that from an imaginary point `{j,*,*}`, if possible, we jump to its corresponding real point `{-j,*,*}`. After that we jump to another real point `{-k,*,*}` (the only connected imaginary point is the point we came from, that is already visited so not allowed) and then we jump back to an imaginary point...

Comment: If we were not to immediately jump to the imaginary point `{k,*,*}`, then then edge  `{{-k,*,*}, {k,*,*}}` can never be used, so that we miss a reward of `bound`, which is not optimal. This is why we get a `tour` with this structure of pairs of real points and pairs of imaginary points. To see that it is optimal, note the following. All configurations of pairs correspond to a correct tour, for example `{{1,5},{3,2}}` corresponds to `{1,5 25, 23, 3, 2, 22, 21, 1}`. Furthermore, the cost of any such tour is `20*bound + costOfPairs`. As `20*bounds` is constant, we are optimizing `costOfPairs`

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145611/21532) can help?And ``Options[GraphComputation`LegacyFindShortestTour]`` also accept a custom `DistanceFunction`

Answer (score 5):

There is a solution based on `IGLargestIndependentVertexSets`,which from [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs)'s package [IGraphM](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM),when the point is less `15` or much less.I mean,the effeciency it very poor.I will produce just `10` points to test it.

#### Built a weight graph with `EuclideanDistance`

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomInteger[20, {10, 2}];
g = CompleteGraph[10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Find a smallest independent vertex sets

```
iden = IGLargestIndependentVertexSets[LineGraph[g]];
pair = List @@@ First[MinimalBy[EdgeList[g][[##]] & /@ iden, 
    Total[EuclideanDistance @@@ N[#]] &]]
```

> {{{5,0},{0,0}},{{7,0},{12,0}},{{2,3},{3,8}},{{16,14},{18,16}},{{19,5},{19,4}}}

```
N[Total[EuclideanDistance @@@ pair]]
```

> `18.9274`

I hope this is a good start..

Comment: @Szabolcs Could I expected `IGLargestIndependentEdgeSets` in future?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is of any value at all but I was curious to see how an optimization approach would work, and this is what I came up with:

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomInteger[20, {20, 2}];

tdist = N @ Total[EuclideanDistance @@@ #] &;

fn[pt_List, x_ /; VectorQ[x, NumberQ]] := tdist @ Partition[pt[[Ordering @ x]], 2]

vars = Unique @ Table["p", {Length @ pts}];

{min, sol} = 
  NMinimize[fn[pts, vars], vars, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing", 
   MaxIterations -> 1000, PrecisionGoal -> 1];

pts[[Ordering[vars /. sol]]] ~Partition~ 2

tdist @ %
```

> ```
> {{{12, 0}, {11, 2}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 4}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 2}}, {{3, 10}, {5, 12}}, 
> {{18, 16}, {16, 14}}, {{17, 11}, {19, 8}}, {{3, 8}, {7, 3}}, {{15, 6}, 
>  {19, 5}}, {{5, 0}, {7, 0}}, {{19, 4}, {20, 3}}}
>
> 31.675
> ```

The same code starting with `pts = RandomInteger[20, {10, 2}];` gives:

> ```
> {{{19, 5}, {19, 4}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 8}}, {{12, 0}, {7, 0}},
>  {{0, 0}, {5, 0}}, {{18, 16}, {16, 14}}}
>
> 18.9274
> ```

Answer (score 4):

[`FindShortestTour`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour.html) appears to be a sub-optimal but fast method.

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomInteger[20, {20, 2}];

tdist = N@Total[EuclideanDistance @@@ #] &;

o = FindShortestTour[pts][[2]];

Partition[# @ pts[[o]], 2] & /@ {Most, Rest};

pairs = MinimalBy[%, tdist, 1][[1]]

tdist @ pairs

ListLinePlot @ pairs
```

> ```
> {{{5, 0}, {4, 2}}, {{2, 3}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 4}, {3, 8}}, {{3, 10}, {5, 12}},
>  {{16, 14}, {18, 16}}, {{17, 11}, {19, 8}}, {{19, 5}, {20, 3}},
>  {{19, 4}, {15, 6}}, {{12, 0}, {11, 2}}, {{7, 3}, {7, 0}}}
>
> 32.0483
> ```

[image]

The same code with `pts = RandomInteger[20, {10, 2}];` gives:

> ```
> {{{7, 0}, {12, 0}}, {{19, 4}, {19, 5}}, {{18, 16}, {16, 14}},
>  {{3, 8}, {2, 3}}, {{0, 0}, {5, 0}}}
>
> 18.9274
> ```

Comment: @yode I did not look at your self-answer closely enough!  Why does your output only have ten points in it?  Shouldn't it have all 20?  I think I misunderstand your problem. :-(

Comment: Sorry,my solution is very slow,so I use `RandomInteger[20, {10, 2}]` to instead of `20`.

Comment: @yode I see.  :-)  I guess you are interested in only the optimal paring and not one that is "close" -- is that correct?  If so I should delete my answers as neither method is optimal.

Comment: Yes,I just expected  the optimal paring and hope to speed up it. :)

Comment: @yode I believe your self-answer is also not an optimal pairing, so I shall not delete my answers at this time.

Comment: See my update please. :)

Comment: Actually I am very happy to see the `FindShortestTour` is used here,but I'm just little suspect that when we get the shortest loop,then we can get the shorest pair from it?But I don't very sure indeed.

Comment: @yode No, I do not think this will always be the shortest pairing, which is why I wrote ***sub-optimal***.  I suspect that to find the true shortest pairing every time will require exhaustive testing and be very slow, as this is true for the Traveling Salesman Problem to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: As your hint,actually I have tried `FindHamiltonianPath`,it is often give a optimal pairing,but not always.

Answer (score 3):

Might not be terribly efficient but this can be done with integer linear programming. It is quite similar to a method shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63918/51) but unfortunately the relaxed problem in this case need not deliver an integer solution.

Here is the example.

```
SeedRandom[1]
len = 20;
pts = RandomInteger[20, {len, 2}];
```

For each `1<=i<j<=20` we'll create a variable to denote whether or not to create an edge between the `i`th and `j`th points. So these are intended as 0-1 variables. We impose constraints that every point be hit by exactly one edge. The objective function will be the sum of all distances between points linked by an edge.

```
ovars = Array[x, {len, len}];
vars = MapIndexed[#1[[#2[[1]] + 1 ;; -1]] &, ovars];
fvars = Flatten[vars];
zeroRule = Thread[Complement[Flatten[ovars], fvars] -> 0];

dists = Table[
   vars[[j, k]]*EuclideanDistance[pts[[j]], pts[[j + k]]], {j, 
    len - 1}, {k, 1, Length[vars[[j]]]}];
obj = Total[dists, 2];
c1 = Thread[
   Map[Total, vars] + (Map[Total, Transpose[ovars]] /. zeroRule) == 1];
c2 = Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, fvars];
```

We solve it with `FindMinimum`.

```
{min, vals} = 
  FindMinimum[{obj, Flatten[{c1, c2, Element[fvars, Integers]}]}, 
   fvars];
```

Now deduce which edges get used.

```
ores = Position[Round[vars /. vals], 1, 2];
res = Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]] + #[[1]]} &, ores]
```

Again cribbing from someone else's graphics, we show the result.

```
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[pts], Red, PointSize[Medium], 
  Arrow[{pts[[#]], pts[[#2]]} & @@@ res]}]
```

[image]

This method handles 150 points in a half minute or so. One bottleneck is the computation of the objective function.

Comment: I have seen your answer many times,give me some time to check the `FindMinimum` always give a global minimal pair.I will response you after some days.