# All Perfect Matchings on a Square Lattice

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

Is there a way to quickly display all the perfect matchings of the vertices of a square lattice?

The following code only finds one:

```
HighlightGraph[
 GridGraph[{4, 4}, VertexStyle -> White, 
  EdgeStyle -> Gray], {Style[
   FindIndependentEdgeSet[GridGraph[{4, 4}]], Blue,Thick]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I will recommend `IGLargestIndependentVertexSets` in [my this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143196/21532)

Comment: Yes it will run faster I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the trick I have used is to construct the [LineGraph](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineGraph.html) of the lattice, and then find all its largest [independent vertex sets](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndependentVertexSet.html).

On e.g. the 4 x 4 square lattice, the following code outputs all 36 perfect matchings of the vertices:

```
    perfectsets[g_] := Module[{},
    allsets = FindIndependentVertexSet[LineGraph[g], Infinity, All];
    maximalsets = {};
    For[i = 1, i <= Length[allsets], i++,
    If[Length[allsets[[i]]] == 2 n,
    maximalsets = Append[maximalsets, allsets[[i]]];
    ];]; maximalsets];

    n = 4;
    g = GridGraph[{n, n}, VertexStyle -> White, 
       EdgeStyle -> {Gray, Thick}];

    matchings = EdgeList[g][[#]] & /@ perfectsets[g];
    ListofPerfectMatchings = 
     Table[HighlightGraph[
       GridGraph[{n, n}, VertexStyle -> White, 
        EdgeStyle -> Gray], {Style[matchings[[i]], Blue, Thick]}], {i, 1, 
       Length[matchings]}]
```

i.e.

[image: All perfect matchings of the vertices of the 4x4 square lattice.]

See also yode's answer [in this post,](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111576/how-to-get-the-perfect-matching-or-near-perfect-matching/143198) which is where I got the idea.

Comment: Note this will find all matchings, not necessarily perfect, so a modification according to yode's comment to the OP will speed things up, but it requires an external package to be installed.

Comment: Also note $n$ must be even for a perfect matching to exist.